# 500 error when implmenting SEO friendly URLs

Tags: seo, htaccess, url

I want to create SEO friendly URL for my website. I am creating a *.htaccess* file but these file not run in Bluehost. Bluehost gets an "Internal Server Error":

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator,
>   webmaster@ompeespace.coraltechnologies.com and inform them of the time
>   the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have
>   caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

I can't understand what did I do.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your htaccess file. Post it here so we can see it and try to troubleshoot it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had implemented URL rewriting using *.htaccess* on Bluehost server a way back. Can't find exact code in my previous company project works but [this article](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect) will help you a lot. I am sure it's syntax error because Apache will not show you user friendly error specially  for *.htaccess*.

Comment: right bro this is error in .htaccessfile. http://www.ompeegroup.com

Comment: m glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting (via *.htaccess*) in a user directory (if not globally enabled) requires two settings in the Apache config. One is to allow the usage of *.htaccess* files via the `AllowOverride` directive. This seems to be the case already, as you receive the `HTTP 500` after adding the rewrites.

Second directive to be set is the `Options +FollowSymLinks`, otherwise a `HTTP 500` is presented (you might wanna check: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

If this also isn't the case, then it might be (as mentioned by John Conde) a syntax error in your `Rewrite` rules or your *.htaccess* file.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check the permissions on the .htaccess file, usually you upload a .htaccess with 777 permissions, and most hosts only run with 644